# Remove up to last backslash from URL using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of URLs in a .txt file that end with a filename - I need to extract that filename. However, the number of backslashes and the strings before each backslash differ across URLs, e.g:

```
https://www.something.com/something/somethingelse/file.zip
https://www.something.com/something/somethingelse/somethingnew/file2.txt
```

In my URLs, both `somethingelse` and `somethingnew` are constants (cannot share actual URLs due to data privacy agreement), but may change in the future. The following code works for the first url, but not the second:

```
sed 's/^.*\/somethingelse\///g' in_file.txt > out_file.txt
```

Is there a `sed` pattern I can use to match everything after the last backslash - therefore not requiring a string constant?

Comment: backslash: \ slash: /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/^.*[/]//' in_file.txt > out_file.txt
```

You have over complicated your reg-ex. Recall that `.*` in regex matches on the "greediest match" principle, that is it will match as far to the right as it can. So whether `somethingelse` or `somethingnew` are part of the match doesn't matter, we're matching all chars until we find the last `/` char in the line.

You could rewrite your expression as

```
 sed 's/^.*\///' in_file.txt > out_file.txt
```

Note that `g` is contradictory in your test case (but doesn't cause a problem)

Comment: Perfect - thanks! I'd been using non-greedy regular expressions in R a lot recently and forgot that regexs in bash were greedy.

Comment: Since –as you say– reg-ex are greedy, you can even do without the initial `^` (though it feels better to have)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `basename` command available in bash, e.g.,:

```
$ basename "https://www.something.com/something/somethingelse/file.zip"
$ file.zip
```

Or if you really want to use sed:

```
sed 's#.*/##' in_file.txt > out_file.txt
```

Comment: You can process the whole input file with `basename` using `xargs`: `<in_file.txt xargs -L 1 basename >out_file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You may use `awk` that doesn't require any regex:

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file
```

```
file.zip
file2.txt
```

If you want to use `sed` only then use:

```
sed 's~.*/~~' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to match only the last content after /

```
 sed 's:.*\/::' in_file.txt > out_file.txt
```

in_file.txt had

```
https://www.something.com/something/somethingelse/file.zip
https://www.something.com/something/somethingelse/somethingnew/file2.txt
https://www.something.com/something/somethingelse/file1.zip
https://www.something.com/something/somethingelse/somethingnew/file4.txt
https://www.something.com/something/somethingelse/somethingnew/file4/random/hello.txt
justafile.txt
```

out_file.txt has

```
file.zip
file2.txt
file1.zip
file4.txt
hello.txt
justafile.txt
```